# MacOS command-line security updates: equivalent for apt-get update all

Tags: terminal, command-line, high-sierra, bash, software-update

I am accustomed to updating systems with [`sudo apt get update`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do) and would like to ensure MacOS [security updates are installed from the command line](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-mac-os-x-update-softwareupdate-bash-shell-command/).  This `software update' command was issued on my machine:

```
$ softwareupdate -l
Software Update Tool
Finding available software
No new software available.
```

The article indicates that the unix equivalent is:

```
sudo softwareupdate -r
```

The list command returned that no updates are available: Can I expect that if there were security updates for the OS, they would be listed for download?  I do not want to be misinterpret the response and think that the box is updated when it is not updated.

Comment: Apple releases security updates usually on a bi-monthly basis. You can check the latest updates at: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201222
So nothing listed is usual..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, security updates show up as recommended updates but `softwareupdate -r` at least on Mojave is invalid.  Note *softwareupdate* will not install updates for things from the App Store.

If you run `softwareupdate -l` on a system that is due security updates you can see them prefixed with a `*` character in the --list output which means they are recommended and will be processed by the `-r` option.

This is from a system untouched for a month - as you can see there is a recommended Safari update and a recommended Security update that requires a restart.

```
Last login: Mon Dec  2 19:21:08 on ttys000
A1398% softwareupdate -l
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
   * Security Update -10.14.6
    Security Update  (10.14.6), 1531842K [recommended] [restart]
   * Safari13.0.4MojaveAuto-13.0.4
    Safari (13.0.4), 67332K [recommended]
A1398%
```

You may either list all available updates with `-l` (which is closest to `sudo apt-get update` in that it doesn't download or install packages), download with `-d` or download and install them with `-i`.  The `-r` switch on its own is not accepted.

---

- To download and *install* recommended updates use `softwareupdate -i -r`.  From `man softwareupdate` :

> ```
>  -i | --install
>              Each update specified by args is downloaded and installed.  args can be one of the
>              following:
>
>             -r | --recommended
>                          All updates that are recommended for your system. These are prefixed
>                          with a * character in the --list output.
> ```

```
A1398% softwareupdate -i -r
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Downloaded Security Update
Downloaded Safari
Installing Security Update , Safari
Done with Safari
Done.

You have installed one or more updates that requires that you restart your computer.
Please restart immediately.
To automate the restart process with softwareupdate(8), use --restart.
A1398%
```

In this case the security update required a restart and this was advised.  The `-R` (capital) or `--restart` option can automate this but you would want to check user session status before forcing a restart and potentially losing session state/unsaved changes/etc.  Passing `--restart` requires root privilege so the command in this case would be `sudo softwareupdate -irR`

---

- Optionally you can *download* and not install recommended software using `softwareupdate -d -r`

> ```
>  -d | --download
>              Each update specified by args is downloaded but not installed. The values of args
>              are the same as for the --install command.
> ```

```
A1398% softwareupdate -d -r
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Downloaded Security Update
Downloaded Safari
Done.
A1398%
```

---

If you wanted *all* instead of *recommended* you would replace `-r` with `-a`.

> ```
>              -a | --all  All updates that are applicable to your system, including those non-
>                          recommended ones, which are prefixed with a - character in the --list
>                          output. (Non-recommended updates are uncommon in any case.)
> ```

---

Note that `sudo` on Mojave is required only for the `--restart` option but this rather old [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/softwareupdate.html) indicates that it was also required for installation in the past.

> ```
> -i
> --install
>    Each update specified by args is downloaded, unarchived, and
>    installed.  This command requires root.
> ```

Comment: Note that some updates require a restart (see the note that `softwareupdate -i -r` printed). Use the `-R` or `--restart` option automates this. But you might want to check user session status before forcing a restart and potentially losing session state/unsaved changes/etc.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - good point, I have included your comments.